# We've updated the Data Subject Rights (DSR) request page

Tags: discussion, legal, announcements, gdpr

We’ve updated the [Data Request page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request) to use a native solution from our consent provider, OneTrust.

### What is changing?

Data Subject Rights (DSR) requests, as a part of Stack Overflow’s global privacy compliance, will now be managed through OneTrust.

While our previous implementation allowed users to submit requests for access (export), erasure, rectification, and restriction of data processing, we’ve added additional request types to meet and exceed industry best practices, regardless of which data protection laws may or may not apply to you. In other words, we have adopted a globally uniform standard that will allow you to make the available DSR requests and Stack Overflow will honor them, regardless of where you are located/reside, so long as a legal exception does not apply.

To access the DSR request page, enter the Legal portal found in the footer of every page on the network. Once there, click on the “Submit Data Request” link in the table of contents on the left hand side.

Below are screenshots comparing the before and after:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

As we previously stated, we have made this change to exceed industry best practices and to better serve our users and their privacy needs. If you have any questions about this change, please post them in an answer below.

Comment: Shouldn't One Trust now be listed as a [subprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/subprocessors) or isn't that needed because we enter our PII directly into their form and submit to their systems?

Comment: Looks like the ZIP code at the bottom is cut off.

Comment: How much data sharing will this cause between Se and One Trust and how much of that is PII?

Comment: But it's only for Stack Overflow. No way to submit request for other sites.

Comment: The form says, "You can use this form to submit a request regarding your personal information that is processed by Stack." Should that be "Stack Exchange", or "Stack Overflow", instead of just "Stack"?

Comment: @rene We are in the process of evaluating all of our subprocessor lists.  In this particular case, OneTrust has been a vendor for quite some time, as both our cookie consent management and consent management platform provider.

Comment: @Mast We have strict access and retention policies employed around user data. The only data shared with OneTrust is what is asked for in the form, which is necessary to fulfill the request.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard When a user submits a data request through the form it applies to all sites in the SE network. This was also true for the previous form.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist as far as I know, it's the internal name used by Stack Overflow (the company) employees, and these days some ordinary members as well. Probably it refers to the company as whole, hence all sites, but there's no way new user or even long time user who isn't in the depth of things to know it.

Comment: @Sasha well, like I said in my previous comment, there no way for ordinary users to know that. All sites link to Stack Overflow, the logo on top of the form is Stack Overflow, and nowhere does it mentions that it can be used for other SE sites.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Thats a good point, thank you. I will give that feedback to the team who worked on this.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Could we get dark mode for the form, please? It looks somewhat odd in dark mode right now (screenshot taken on Microsoft Edge w/ a mobile device, but I suspect dark mode also does not work for the form on desktop, too)

[image]

Comment: That might be hard to achieve given that form sits in an iframe and isn't hosted by SE.